# SyntaxError: not a chance — What is this error?

Tags: python, syntax-error, curly-braces

I tried to execute the following code on a Python IDLE

```
from __future__ import braces
```

And I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: not a chance
```

What does the above error mean?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You have found an easter egg in Python. It is a joke.

It means that delimiting blocks by braces instead of indentation will never be implemented.

*Normally*, imports from the [special `__future__` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) enable features that are backwards-incompatible, such as the `print()` function, or true division.

So the line `from __future__ import braces` is taken to mean you want to enable the 'create blocks with braces' feature, and the exception tells you your chances of that *ever* happening are nil.

You can add that to the long list of in-jokes included in Python, just like `import __hello__`, `import this` and `import antigravity`. The Python developers have a well-developed sense of humour!

Comment: For folks puzzled by "not a chance", which is slang, it means that there is no possibility or probability of the thing happening.

Comment: I ask myself if it would be theoretically possible to implement that - as an extension - in python. (I'm not a python developer)

Comment: @hek2mgl http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/whython-python-for-people-who-hate-whitespace/

Comment: @chepner `Less Whitespace, More Enterprise` :D Thanks!

Comment: It's less funny for blind people trying to deal with Python on a screen reader. For them the reliance on white-space for blocks makes reading and writing code difficult. At least that's been my experience working with blind kids.

Comment: @dumbledad that was perhaps true a decade ago, but screen readers have since learned to voice indentation information.

Comment: Have they - JAWS seems not to cope well. I'll do more research. Which one were you using for well voiced indentation information?

Comment: @dumbledad: All my experience is indirect, but I heard positive stories supporting NVDA, EdSharp and Orca; I note that both Orca and NVDA are primarily written in Python! Also, Python is not the only programming language with significant whitespace.

Comment: Nope, COBOL too. Both for the same reason (as far as I can tell): readability

Comment: @dumbledad: Haskell, CoffeeScript, Miranda, Occam, and F# all use whitespace in the syntax. Note: this comment thread is getting way out of hand; please join the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) if you want to discuss further.

Answer (score 40):

The `__future__` module is normally used to provide features from future versions of Python.

This is an easter egg that summarizes its developers' feelings on this issue.

There are several more:

`import this` will display the zen of Python.

`import __hello__` will display `Hello World...`.

In Python 2.7 and 3.0, `import antigravity` will open the browser to a comic!

Answer (score 2):

It means that writing Python code like:

```
def hello() {
    print("Hello");
    print("World");
}
```

instead of

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")
    print("World")
```

will never happen. One is both faster to type and easier to understand. Can you tell which one?

Oh, and someone made [this](https://writeonly.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/whython-python-for-people-who-hate-whitespace/).

Comment: Re *"someone made this"*: That was published on [1st April](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/April_fool#Noun).